# Write to Windows disk fails

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, mount, delete

I have Ubuntu (Version 20.10) on one disk, and Windows (10) on another physical disk in my dual boot system. I have been successfully reading from and writing to the Windows disk from within Linux for several months. This changed recently, possibly as a result of a driver update in Windows.
I have disabled the Windows 'fast start up', and tried going into Linux after restarting, but no difference.
The Windows disk is mounted, and the permissions information is the same for my Linux drive when I access it with Caja file manager.
Running some commands in the terminal gave these results:

> $ df
> df: /run/user/1000/doc: Operation not permitted
> Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
> tmpfs             804260      1712    802548   1% /run
> /dev/sda5      474840096  70993164 379656676  16% /
> tmpfs            4021292         0   4021292   0% /dev/shm
> tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
> tmpfs               4096         0      4096   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
> /dev/sda2         524272     10968    513304   3% /boot/efi
> tmpfs             804256       148    804108   1% /run/user/1000
> /dev/sda1      483975216     72036 459248968   1% /media/philip/UbuntuPhil
> /dev/nvme0n1p3 498799612 104113996 394685616  21% /media/philip/Windows

> $ ntfsfix /dev/nvme0n1p3
> Mounting volume... Error opening read-only '/dev/nvme0n1p3': Permission denied
> FAILED
> Attempting to correct errors... Error opening read-only '/dev/nvme0n1p3': Permission denied
> FAILED
> Failed to startup volume: Permission denied
> Error opening '/dev/nvme0n1p3': Read-only file system
> Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
> "Could not save the file “/media/philip/Windows/Do…ws updates, Dec 2020 .txt”.You are trying to save the file on a read-only disk. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.

> $ fdisk /dev/nvme0n1p3
> Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36).
> Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
> Be careful before using the write command.
> fdisk: cannot open /dev/nvme0n1p3: Permission denied

The problem seems to have arisen after these driver updates in Windows:

> Flash BIOS Update for Lenovo V530s-07ICR, ThinkCentre M720e - 10 [64] - M30KT21A
> Successfully installed: 23/12/2020 8:25 am

> Lenovo SSD Firmware Update Tool - 10 [64] - 40
> Successfully installed: 16/12/2020 9:44 am

Comment: Nothing to report from me -- the situation remains the same. The disk is mounted and I can read from it, but I can't write to it. I would be very happy to run any sort of Linux command that would throw some light on what this on-going problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys, but I managed to pull myself out of the problem anyhow. This website (after https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/mount-windows-10-in-ubuntu/) gave instructions that solved the problem.
In a nutshell, using DISKS the trick was to disable “Automatic Mount Options” and add "remove_hiberfile" to the end of the text box.